# Warning for Dynamic Combobox list

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox that builds it's list upon first usage.  I know that the way I want "NotInList" to behave isn't conventional - I don't want to waste adding the item to a table separate from the needed entry, but I'd like to still warn about an item that hasn't been used yet, so that the user has to think twice before accepting the entry.

Once the user adds the item, it will automatically appear in the list next time because the data source for the combo box is as follows:

```
SELECT tbl_SP.PROGRAM
FROM tbl_SP
GROUP BY tbl_SP.PROGRAM
HAVING (((tbl_SP.PROGRAM) Is Not Null And (tbl_SP.PROGRAM)<>""));
```

I tried this:

```
Private Sub cmbPROGRAM_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    If MsgBox("'" & Chr(34) & NewData & Chr(34) & " hasn't been used yet. Add to list? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Add - " & NewData & "?") = vbYes Then
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If

End Sub
```

but of course, Access wants the item to actually exist before it will release the error. And...if I set LimitToList to "No" then the user doesn't get a warning.

## How can I achieve this behavior?

Ok, I tried this which works fine if the user selects YES, but becomes more complicated when the user selects "NO"

```
Public Function ReturnsRecords(strSQL As String) As Boolean
Dim d As DAO.Database
Dim arr(1 To 3) As DAO.Recordset
'Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    'assume 3 items in array above
    Set d = CurrentDb
    Set arr(1) = d.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
   ' MsgBox "Record Count is " & arr(1).RecordCount

    If arr(1).RecordCount > 0 Then
       ReturnsRecords = True
    Else
        ReturnsRecords = False
    End If
    Set d = Nothing


End Function

Private Sub cmbPROGRAM_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "Select * from LU_PROGRAM where PROGRAM ='" & Me.cmbPROGRAM & "'"

    If ReturnsRecords(strSQL) = False Then

        If MsgBox("'" & Chr(34) & Me.cmbPROGRAM & Chr(34) & " hasn't been used yet. Add to list? ", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Add - " & Me.cmbPROGRAM & "?") = vbNo Then

            Cancel = True
           ' how do I reset this?  Me.cmbPROGRAM.Text = Null
        End If

    End If
  End Sub
```

How do I clear the combobox  if the user selects NO? If I select me.undo, that will undo all of the entries, but I just want to clear the combobox.

Incidentally, the form is totally unbound and doesn't accept an entry until the user selects "Save"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm not quite sure what you wish to achieve ...

Then, educate the users to press *Escape* to cancel. This is mandatory wisdom when operating an Access application.

For your code to work, you can't change the content of a control in the *BeforeUpdate* event. So try the *AfterUpdate* event with either:

```
Me!cmbPROGRAM.Text = ""
```

or:

```
Me!cmbPROGRAM.Value = Null
```

Comment: Thank you. It's my unbound form that makes it a challenge.  I was hoping to avoid creating look up libraries, but I think it has finally come to